# Batch File is Slow

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo Off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set webServer="\\serverweb01a\location"
set AppServer="\\serverapp01a\location"

echo checking file on App servers
echo ------------------------------------ >>log.txt
echo ************App Servers************* >>log.txt

Call:FindModifiedDateTimeApp %AppServer%

echo checking file on web servers
echo ------------------------------------ >>log.txt
echo ************Web Servers************* >>log.txt

Call:FindModifiedDateTimeWeb %webServer% 
set /p Done=Done... 
goto:eof


:FindModifiedDateTimeWeb

set c=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File_List.txt) do (
    set /a c+=1
    set sources[!c!]=%%i
)



for /r "%~1"  %%a in (*) do (
   for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set sources[') do (      
      if "%%~nxa"=="%%s" (
        echo %%~ta : %%~dpnxa  >>log.txt
        call:CheckOtherWebServers "%%~dpnxa" Serverweb01b
        call:CheckOtherWebServers "%%~dpnxa" Serverweb01d
    )

  )
)
goto:eof


:CheckOtherWebServers

 set server2=%~2
set Temps=%~1
set Temps=%Temps:Serverweb01a=!server2!%
for /f "delims=" %%f IN ("%Temps%") Do echo %%~tf : %%f >>log.txt
goto:eof

:FindModifiedDateTimeApp

set c=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (Test.txt) do (
set /a c+=1
set sources[!c!]=%%i
)
for /r "%~1"  %%a in (*) do (
   for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set sources[') do (
        if "%%~nxa"=="%%s" (
          echo %%~ta : %%~dpnxa  >>log.txt
          call:CheckOtherAppServers "%%~dpnxa" ServerApp01b
          call:CheckOtherAppServers "%%~dpnxa" ServerApp01d
    )
 )
)
goto:eof

:CheckOtherAppServers

set server2=%~2
set Temps=%~1
set Temps=%Temps:ServerApp01a=!server2!%
for /f "delims=" %%f IN ("%Temps%") Do echo %%~tf : %%f >>log.txt
goto:eof
```

Above is My batch which I made to search certain files which are mentioned in "file_List.txt" file and find their last modified time.(There may be one file or multiple files)
I need to find the files on 3 web servers and 3 app servers. Location of file would be the same for all web servers and app servers.
So, I planned to do it in following way:

search on web server    serverweb01a. Get the location of file say file found at \serverweb01a\location\bin\abc.dll. Search for the file at location \serverweb01b\location\bin\abc.dll and then \serverweb01d\location\bin\abc.dll

similar steps for app server.

Script is working absolutely fine but it's little slow. Any idea how can i make it faster?

Comment: Find out what's causing the slowness - the network or the code itself - by commenting the lines with the actual network access. If it's the network then maybe listing the remote folder with `dir` into a temporary file/variable will make it faster. If it's the code itself then it's because you're using arrays. Either way before speeding up something a bottleneck should be pinpointed.

Comment: Using function CALLS in batch can create a lot of overhead. There is a thead over on DosTips.com that talks about this and about how to use macros instead of CALLS to speed up your scripts. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1827